# Same Start time for 500 cloudlets in a shared VM. I'm not getting it

Tags: java, cloud, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm trying to run 500 Cloudlets on a single VM using CLOUDSIM but in every case START TIME for every cloudlets are same. So I thought when a single job is executing another will wait, but here every cloudlets are starting together. I'm not getting it. Please help me to understand. I'm Out of Characters here so I can't show all 500 cloudlets but here is the sample.

```
package org.cloudbus.cloudsim.examples;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Cloudlet;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.CloudletSchedulerTimeShared;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Datacenter;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.DatacenterBroker;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.DatacenterCharacteristics;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Host;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Log;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Pe;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Storage;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.UtilizationModel;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.UtilizationModelFull;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Vm;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.VmAllocationPolicySimple;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.VmSchedulerTimeShared;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.BwProvisionerSimple;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.PeProvisionerSimple;
import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.RamProvisionerSimple;

import sun.font.CreatedFontTracker;
    /** Here Cloudlet number = 2 & VM Number = 1 **/

public class MyExample2 {

    private static List<Cloudlet> cloudletList;
    private static List<Vm> vmlist;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Log.printLine("Starting MyExample2");
        try { 

            int user_no = 1; // here we have 2 user so we will use 2 cloudlets
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            boolean traceFlag = false;

            //Initialize cloudsim library
            CloudSim.init(user_no, cal, traceFlag);

            //datacenter creation
            Datacenter center_0 = create_Datacenter("center_0");//creat_Datacenter("") is user defined method

            //creat broker
            DatacenterBroker broker = create_Broker();//creat_Broker() is user defined
            int brokerid = broker.getId();

            //creation of VM
            vmlist = new ArrayList<Vm>();

            // VM description
                        int vmid = 0;
                        int mips = 1000;
                        long size = 10000; // image size (MB)
                        int ram = 512; // vm memory (MB)
                        long bw = 1000;
                        int pesNumber = 1; // number of cpus
                        String vmm = "Xen"; // VMM name

                        /*int vmid2 = 1;
                        int mips2 = 1000;
                        long size2 = 10000; // image size (MB)
                        int ram2 = 512; // vm memory (MB)
                        long bw2 = 1000;
                        int pesNumber2 = 1; // number of cpus
                        String vmm2 = "Xen"; // VMM name*/

                        // create VM
                        Vm vm = new Vm(vmid, brokerid, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerTimeShared());
                        //Vm vm2 = new Vm(vmid2, brokerid, mips2, pesNumber2, ram2, bw2, size2, vmm2, new CloudletSchedulerTimeShared());

            //add the VM in VM list
            vmlist.add(vm);
            //vmlist.add(vm2);

            //submit the VM list to the broker
            broker.submitVmList(vmlist);//<-----------WHY WE DOING THIS-------------<<<<<


            //description of 2 cloudlets

            //creation of CloudLet1
            int id1 = 0;
            long length1 = 40000;//Time varies with cloudlet length
            long filesize1 = 300;
            long outputsize1 = 300;
            UtilizationModel UM1 = new UtilizationModelFull();//

            //creation of CloudLet2
            int id2 = 1;
            long length2 = 1500;
            long filesize2 = 100;
            long outputsize2 = 300;
            UtilizationModel UM2 = new UtilizationModelFull();// 

            //finalizing above to cloudlets
            Cloudlet cloudlet1 = new Cloudlet(id1, length1, pesNumber, filesize1, outputsize1, UM1, UM1, UM1);
            cloudlet1.setUserId(brokerid);

            Cloudlet cloudlet2 = new Cloudlet(id2, length2, pesNumber, filesize2, outputsize2, UM2, UM2, UM2);
            cloudlet2.setUserId(brokerid);

            ArrayList<Cloudlet> clet = new ArrayList<Cloudlet>();//Listing the cloudlets in a List to creat more cloudlets
            id2++;
            for(int i=id2; i<=500; i++){

                Cloudlet cloudlet = new Cloudlet(i, length2, pesNumber, filesize2, outputsize2, UM2, UM2, UM2);
                cloudlet.setUserId(brokerid);
                clet.add(cloudlet);
            }

            cloudletList = new ArrayList<Cloudlet>();

            //adding cloudlets to cloudletlist
            cloudletList.add(cloudlet1);
            cloudletList.add(cloudlet2);

            Iterator<Cloudlet> ctr = clet.iterator();

            while(ctr.hasNext()) {

                cloudletList.add(ctr.next());
            }

            //submit cloudlet to broker
            broker.submitCloudletList(cloudletList);

            //bind the cloudlets to the vms. This way, the broker
            // will submit the bound cloudlets only to the specific VM

            broker.bindCloudletToVm(cloudlet1.getCloudletId(),vm.getId());


            //broker.bindCloudletToVm(cloudlet2.getCloudletId(),vm2.getId());


            Iterator<Cloudlet> itr = cloudletList.iterator();

            //getting file size
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                System.out.println("***************Size*************");
                System.out.println(itr.next().getCloudletFileSize());
                System.out.println("***************Size*************");
            }


            //start SIMULATION
            CloudSim.startSimulation();

            //Final step: Print results when simulation is over
            List<Cloudlet> newList = broker.getCloudletReceivedList();//check this method

            CloudSim.stopSimulation();


            printCloudletList(newList);



        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.printLine("Unwanted errors happen");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the datacenter.
     *
     * @param name the name
     *
     * @return the datacenter
     */
    private static Datacenter create_Datacenter(String name) {

        // Here are the steps needed to create a PowerDatacenter:
        // 1. We need to create a list to store
        // our machine
        List<Host> hostList = new ArrayList<Host>();

        // 2. A Machine contains one or more PEs or CPUs/Cores.
        // In this example, it will have only one core.
        List<Pe> peList = new ArrayList<Pe>();

        int mips = 2000;

        // 3. Create PEs and add these into a list.
        peList.add(new Pe(0, new PeProvisionerSimple(mips))); // need to store Pe id and MIPS Rating

        // 4. Create Host with its id and list of PEs and add them to the list
        // of machines
        int hostId = 0;
        int ram = 2048; // host memory (MB)
        long storage = 1000000; // host storage
        int bw = 10000;

        hostList.add(
            new Host(
                hostId,
                new RamProvisionerSimple(ram),
                new BwProvisionerSimple(bw),
                storage,
                peList,
                new VmSchedulerTimeShared(peList)
            )
        ); // This is our machine

        // 5. Create a DatacenterCharacteristics object that stores the
        // properties of a data center: architecture, OS, list of
        // Machines, allocation policy: time- or space-shared, time zone
        // and its price (G$/Pe time unit).
        String arch = "x86"; // system architecture
        String os = "Linux"; // operating system
        String vmm = "Xen";
        double time_zone = 10.0; // time zone this resource located
        double cost = 3.0; // the cost of using processing in this resource
        double costPerMem = 0.05; // the cost of using memory in this resource
        double costPerStorage = 0.001; // the cost of using storage in this
                                        // resource
        double costPerBw = 0.0; // the cost of using bw in this resource
        LinkedList<Storage> storageList = new LinkedList<Storage>(); // we are not adding SAN
                                                    // devices by now

        DatacenterCharacteristics characteristics = new DatacenterCharacteristics(
                arch, os, vmm, hostList, time_zone, cost, costPerMem,
                costPerStorage, costPerBw);

        // 6. Finally, we need to create a PowerDatacenter object.
        Datacenter datacenter = null;
        try {
            datacenter = new Datacenter(name, characteristics, new VmAllocationPolicySimple(hostList), storageList, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return datacenter;
    }
    // We strongly encourage users to develop their own broker policies, to
        // submit vms and cloudlets according
        // to the specific rules of the simulated scenario
        /**
         * Creates the broker.
         *
         * @return the datacenter broker
         */
        private static DatacenterBroker create_Broker() {
            DatacenterBroker broker = null;
            try {
                broker = new DatacenterBroker("Broker");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return broker;
        }
        /**
         * Prints the Cloudlet objects.
         *
         * @param list list of Cloudlets
         */
        private static void printCloudletList(List<Cloudlet> list) {
            int size = list.size();
            Cloudlet cloudlet;

            String indent = "    ";
            Log.printLine();
            Log.printLine("========== OUTPUT ==========");
            Log.printLine("Cloudlet ID" + indent + "STATUS" + indent
                    + "Data center ID" + indent + "VM ID" + indent + "Time" + indent
                    + "Start Time" + indent + "Finish Time");

            DecimalFormat dft = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                cloudlet = list.get(i);
                Log.print(indent + cloudlet.getCloudletId() + indent + indent);

                if (cloudlet.getCloudletStatus() == Cloudlet.SUCCESS) {
                    Log.print("SUCCESS");

                    Log.printLine(indent + indent + cloudlet.getResourceId()
                            + indent + indent + indent + cloudlet.getVmId()
                            + indent + indent
                            + dft.format(cloudlet.getActualCPUTime()) + indent
                            + indent + dft.format(cloudlet.getExecStartTime())
                            + indent + indent
                            + dft.format(cloudlet.getFinishTime()) + indent + indent + indent + cloudlet.getWaitingTime() + indent + indent + cloudlet.getSubmissionTime());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

> ```
> ========== OUTPUT ==========
> Cloudlet ID    STATUS    Data center ID    VM ID    Time    Start Time    Finish Time
>     1        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     2        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     3        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     4        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     5        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     6        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     7        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     8        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     9        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     10        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     11        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     12        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     13        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     14        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     15        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     16        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     17        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     18        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     19        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     20        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     21        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     22        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     23        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     24        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     25        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     26        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     27        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     28        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     29        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     30        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     31        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     32        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     33        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     34        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     35        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     36        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     37        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     38        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     39        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     40        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     41        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     42        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     43        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     44        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     45        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     46        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     47        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     48        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     49        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     50        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     51        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     52        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     53        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     54        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     55        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     56        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     57        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     58        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     59        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     60        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     61        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     62        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     63        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     64        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     65        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     66        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     67        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     68        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     69        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     70        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     71        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     72        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     73        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     74        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     75        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     76        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     77        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     78        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     79        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     80        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     81        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     82        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     83        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     84        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     85        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     86        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     87        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     88        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     89        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     90        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     91        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     92        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     93        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     94        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     95        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     96        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     97        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     98        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     99        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     100        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     101        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     102        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     103        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     104        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     105        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     106        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     107        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     108        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     109        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     110        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     111        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     112        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     113        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     114        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     115        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     116        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     117        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     118        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     119        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     120        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     121        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     122        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     123        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     124        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     125        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     126        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     127        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     128        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     129        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     130        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     131        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     132        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     133        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     134        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     135        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     136        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     137        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     138        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     139        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     140        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     141        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     142        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     143        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     144        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     145        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     146        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     147        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     148        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     149        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     150        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     151        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     152        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     153        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
>     154        SUCCESS        2            0        751        0.1        751.1            0.0        0.1
> ```

Answer (score 3):

use `CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared()` instead of `CloudletSchedulerTimeShared()` when creating `VMs`.